# Getting rid of Spring logs in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring-mvc and security for my Java web application that runs on Tomcat 7. I have customized spring security by extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and to catch a custom exception, I have a class which extends ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.

Now, when I get an exception, whether runtime or not, I am not able to see the cause of the exception in my tomcat logs. Tomcat produces a log which is all about the classes in spring security chain and ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver class.

How can I get my default logs back?

Example log:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:927)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:150)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   com.cagatay.deneme.server.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:65)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>
> **root cause** java.lang.NullPointerException
>   com.cagatay.deneme.server.controller.errorhandler.ErrorController.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ErrorController.java:40)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1148)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:985)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:150)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   com.cagatay.deneme.server.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:65)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)

Answer (score 0):

As per the stacktrace, looks like you've got a problem with a `NullPointerException` on line 40 in `com.cagatay.deneme.server.controller.errorhandler.ErrorController`.  You'll need to find out what causes this and fix it.

EDIT:

According to the [docs for AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.html#doResolveException%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Exception%29), the exception handler should return a `ModelAndView`.  In your code, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.  Now without looking at your code, I don't know whether you are rethrowing an exception, but the stacktrace leads me to believe that the NPE originates in line 40.  IMHO, the exception handler shouldn't throw an exception itself.

Comment: No, that was just an example and the error was in another class. ErrorController is the name of my extended class from ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.

Comment: Thanks for update beny, but you see my main problem is irrelevant data in my logs. At the example above, spring security fills the whole stacktrace.

Comment: But the stacktrace is relevant, as it is pointing to a bug in your ErrorController...

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong, Errorcontroller is the class that extends ExceptionResolver, the exception is thrown somewhere else and is caught there, this is why logs are about it, my complaint is about this case.

Comment: If the exception were thrown elsewhere, it wouldn't say `root cause: NullPointerException` at line 40 of your `ErrorController`.  I would set a breakpoint a debug just to double check...

Answer (score 0):

At the highest level, you can catch any expected and unexpected exceptions and manually log them yourself as you want them to appear instead of letting them propagate to Spring and letting it do its own thing.

One way to do this would be using an ExceptionHandler. Example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-example/